# Gtmetrix site performance

Tags: wordpress, gtmetrix

whose purpose to measure the performance of a site I used GTMETRIX, it returned me patches, I did not understand this point of css images sprites, I searched but I did not find results explanatory.

Is there anyone who has encountered this trick of css images sprite? how to make them perform
thank you
[image: sprite css images]

Answer (score 1):

CSS sprites are used to reduce the number of HTTP requests send to server. The smaller images are combined into a larger one at defined X and Y coordinates. After assigning this generated image to relevant page elements, using the background-position CSS property we can then shift the visible area to the required component image.

Comment: but each small image has its own link  , is it possible after combining them into a one image in which the small part has its link ?

Comment: No, you cannot make a link to an area of an image.